# Minimizing dependencies for Linux shared library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c++11

I am writing a shared library that I am deploying under Windows, Linux and Mac. On the Linux side, I am attempting to make sure that my library has as few dependencies as possible. I don't want the end developer to have to worry at all about what my library uses internally, and in particular I don't want to force them to install anything.

When I run ldd on my library at the moment, I see:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf57fe000)                                        
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb773d000)     
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb7654000)   
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb74a1000)                 
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7782000)                                         
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb745d000)                 
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7440000)
```

This looks fairly reasonable to me, but some of these libraries I am not really sure what they are. Can anyone tell me whether this list of dependencies is reasonable, or whether I can get rid of some of these? With this list of dependencies, will my library run on a wide array of Linux configurations and distros? That is what I am aiming for, maximum portability.

When compiling, I am specifying the flag -static-libgcc. Are there any more flags I can specify to link in the C++ standard library as well, for example? Internally my library uses std::thread in C++11, but I don't want to force the application writer to necessarily have that available (if they are using an older version of GCC for instance).

Update:

I am now specifying -static-libstdc++, in addition to -static-libgcc. My dependency list now looks as follows:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf57fe000)                                        
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7737000)     
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7584000)                 
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77a2000)
```

The only ones that cause me concern are libc.so.6, and linux-gate.so.1. I don't know what these are. Are they old, and if so have they remained backwards compatible for a long time? If so I will just keep them linking dynamically, but otherwise I have to continue investigating. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Which linux distros do you want to target?  I think this is a difficult problem to solve.

Comment: As many as possible really. I have no particular preferences. My build machine is Ubuntu 13, 32 bit.

Comment: This is horribly complicated.  One option would be to provide your developer clients with a static library, but there are still some runtime deps to solve with that as well.

Comment: @PhilipBennefall: libpthread, libc and libstdc++ should be obvious, ld-linux is responsible for loading dynamic libs at runtime, libm is the C Math library, libgcc_s is the GCC support library. I have to pass on linux-gate though.

Comment: @thokra: Is there a trivial (and recommended) way of linking some or all of these dependencies statically, as to avoid forcing the end user to have a C++11 standard library on their system for instance? I am surprised that that is still linked dynamically, since I do specify -static-libgcc.

Comment: @PhilipBennefall: See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html The corresponding switch is -static-libstdc++.

Comment: I don't think you should try to minimize dependencies on essential system shared libraries like `libc.so.6` or `libpthread.so` (or even `libstdc++.so`) ; they exist for a lot of good reasons.

Comment: @thokra: Thanks for that link. I have now added this option, and updated my question. I am basically looking to find out whether or not I have to get rid of any of the remaining dependencies that ldd reports.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: If I don't do that, and I use C++ 11 features for instance, my library won't run on earlier versions of Ubuntu or other distros that don't have a recent version of the GCC libraries installed, correct? That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Then the *only* library you should statically link is `libstdc++` (and keep the others libraries dynamically linked)

Comment: A simpler way might be to make your library free software, and make packages for few major distribitions (and leave the burden of packaging it to others).

Comment: @PhilipBennefall: BTW, libc.so.6 is simply what the name suggests: The GNU implementation of C11 (in its most recent version).

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: That's what I am currently doing. I am specifying -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++. When linking pthreads for example, I just say -lpthreads and ldd reports pthreads as a dynamic dependency, along with a few other things which is what I updated my question with more information about.

Comment: I can't make it free software. It is very much a commercial product.

Comment: Then your company has to invest enough efforts to package it for several distributions.

Comment: @thokra: What will happen if libc.so.6 does not exist on the target machine? Will the loader attempt to find a version independent copy of libc, or will it attempt to use a later version perhaps? It would be unfortunate if it was hardcoded to that exact version just because that's what I'm using on my development machine. That's when I am thinking that static linking would be preferable.

Comment: If `libc.so.6` (or `libpthread.so`) don't exist (a very unlikely possibility) your library won't work. If you link statically the `libc` you are much more tied to the particular set of kernel versions your static libc is supporting.... Static linkage is not the silver bullet you want it to be.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Can you recommend the most widely used distros? My understanding is that many distros are derivatives of other ones, so if I could find the ones that have the most derivants I would be able to at least minimize the number of distros for which I have to deploy the software.

Comment: You say that it is unlikely that libc.so.6 does not exist. Why is that? Wouldn't there be libc.so.5, libc.so.4 etc that could just as likely be the prefered version on a given system? Can I make it link to a version independent copy of libc? libpthreads.so already seems to be version independent.

Comment: libc is one of the building blocks of any Linux distribution - at least AFAIK. If you're running Ubuntu and libc goes missing, you're in huge trouble.

Comment: @thokra: I understand. My main concern is that my library seems to depend on a very specific version of libc, libc.so.6 in this case. I don't know for how long that has been available, and what will happen when libc.so.7 comes along. I'd feel much better if it were libc.so, just like the case is for libpthreads.so. Is there any way of making it not depend on a particular version?

Comment: "Is there any way of making it not depend on a particular version?" --- you are not the very first person in the world that tries to minimize library dependencies. Just trust me on that. A lot of people have put huge, mindboggling, ginormously minbogglingly huge amount of thought and effort into this problem. The result is the default configuration that involves linking to `libc.so.6` dynamically. **Use it**. You are rather unlikely to do better without expending comparable amount of effort.

Comment: I have no problem linking dynamically to it, but what I am wondering is whether this .6 at the end denotes a very specific version that must be available? Is there no way to link to a version independent copy, as seems to be the case with libpthread.so?

Comment: @PhilipBennefall: libc.so.5 was the name of the last "Linux libc", which was a fork of glibc. Since glibc 2.0 in 1997, the shared object's is name libc.so.6 so unless you go back to a Linux distro from before glibc 2.0, you're not gonna find anything but libc.so.6.

Comment: " I am wondering is whether this .6 at the end denotes a very specific version that must be available" --- the short answer is no, `.6` is there for more than a decade and is likely to outlast your own library. The long answer is too long to fit here (in this comment field *or* on this site). Please read at least [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) on libc and most of the material linked from there if you want to have a useful discussion on this subject.

Comment: @thokra: Thanks very much, this is all I was looking to find out. I will let it depend on libc.so.6 and not worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linux-gate.so.1 is a virtual DSO, meaning it doesn't really exist. The best way to explain it is just to read this link [Here](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/).

To answer your question, I think your best choice is to continue linking dynamically to both of them and do a few different builds to target different distros. I have found that typically when you build for Ubuntu, it will work on several of the Debian linux systems.

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend some other distributions that I could build for that would make it work indirectly on others? I have Ubuntu here, but have the ability to install others virtually. Can you recommend any main ones that will give me the best possible coverage?

Comment: Building for Fedora(aka Red Hat), Ubuntu, and Suse will give you pretty good coverage.  Many distributions are based on either Debian or Red Hat so those two alone will go a long way.